# How to run dos commands in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

can we write a script in python that runs dos commands/dos mode?
Eg: I have a command

```
megarec.exe -cleanflash .1
```

which supposed to run only on dos mode.I do it manually.Now i need to write a script which automates the above procedure.can i do it?

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(["megarec.exe", "-cleanflash", ".1"])`

Comment: thank you.Don't mind me asking! Does it actually enters the dos and executes??

Comment: I know very little about windows but yes it should work, one way to know for sure is to try it ;)

Comment: The command i mentioned above is only dos bootable. It did not work as you suggested!

Comment: I have no idea what *is only dos bootable.* means

Comment: It's not "DOS". It's the Windows command line.

Comment: I recommend to use: shlex.split

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
ch=subprocess.Popen("megarec.exe -cleanflash .1",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subrocess.PIPE)
output,err=ch.communicate()
if output:
     print "success:",output
else:
     print "error:",error
```

Comment: Your answer is suboptimal: you are using `shell=True` (which introduces security issues) when there is no need for it, and you are using `Popen` when `call` would solve the problem in a simpler way.

Comment: @Bakuriu What about subprocess.call()? Or run()?

Comment: see the duplicate with a discussion about the alternatives.